# Worksheet_Changed Method for code generated Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet

I'm creating a Worksheet by Code and add some value.
Now I want to check wheater the value in Column C has changed and want to change the value of column D too.
I found the sub Worksheet_Change to do this. But this method is not working for my created worksheet, it's working for the sheet I came from.
Can someone help me please?

I'm setting the Worksheet to active using ws.activate, but it's not working like I want it to work.

```
Sub Test()

Dim monat As Integer
Dim jahr As Integer
Dim tag As Integer
Dim anzahlTage As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim kalenderTag As Date

On Error GoTo Fehler

jahr = Worksheets("Kalender erstellen").Cells(2, 2).Value
monat = Worksheets("Kalender erstellen").Cells(2, 1).Value

anzahlTage = DateSerial(jahr, monat + 1, 1) _
           - DateSerial(jahr, monat, 1)

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
ws.Name = MonthName(monat) + " " + CStr(jahr)

ws.Cells(1, 1) = "Datum"
ws.Cells(1, 2) = "Wochentag"
ws.Cells(1, 3) = "Beginn"
ws.Cells(1, 4) = "Ende"
ws.Cells(1, 5) = "Stunden"
ws.Cells(1, 6) = "Über-/Unterstunden"
ws.Cells(1, 8) = "Stunden gesamt"
ws.Cells(1, 9) = "Urlaub gesamt"

ws.range("A1", "I33").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
ws.range("A1", "I1").Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
ws.Columns("B").ColumnWidth = 20
ws.Columns("F").ColumnWidth = 20
ws.Columns("H").ColumnWidth = 25
ws.Columns("I").ColumnWidth = 25
ws.range("A2", "I2").MergeCells = True

ws.Activate

For tag = 1 To anzahlTage

kalenderTag = DateSerial(jahr, monat, tag)
ws.Cells(tag + 2, 1) = kalenderTag
ws.Cells(tag + 2, 2) = Format$(kalenderTag, "dddd")

Next tag

'Dim rng As range
'Set rng = ActiveSheet.range("A1", "F1")
'With rng.Borders
'.LineStyle = xlContinous
'.Color = vbBlack
'.Weight = xlThin
'End With

'MsgBox (anzahlTage)

Exit Sub
Fehler:

MsgBox "FehlerNr.: " & Err.Number & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
    & "Beschreibung: " & Err.Description _
    , vbCritical, "Fehler"

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As range)

If Not Application.Intersect(Target, range("C3", "C33")) Is Nothing Then
MsgBox ("TEST")

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the code to work in a newly created worksheet, it must be inserted into the worksheet code for the new sheet.
It is easier to `.Copy` an existing worksheet that already has the macro installed than to `.Add` a fresh worksheet.

You get the added benefit that the `.Copied` worksheet can have pre-formatted column, rows, headers, etc.

Comment: Works very good for me and I was able to cut down the VBA Code, thanks.
This is how it's working for me:

`sheetName = MonthName(monat) + " " + CStr(jahr)

Worksheets("Template").Copy After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)

ActiveSheet.Name = sheetName`

Comment: @PhilippRosengart  **Good job!**

Answer (score 0):

You should use the VBE.VBCOMPONENT of this worksheet and add (as a string) your code into its sheet module. The worksheet_change only works in the sheet... that holds the code.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, although I'd still say use @Gary's Students answer, is to use the `Workbook_SheetChange` event.

Add this code to any normal module:

```
Option Explicit
Public SheetCodeName As String

Sub CreateSheet()
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet

    'Add the worksheet and remember the codename for it.
    Set wrkSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    SheetCodeName = wrkSht.CodeName
End Sub
```

In the `ThisWorkBook` module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Sh.CodeName = SheetCodeName Then
        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("C3", "C33")) Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox ("TEST")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

As I said - Garys answer is better as this will start getting complicated very quickly if you're adding lots of sheets (a template sheet will just work).